# Remove whitespace using PIG

Tags: csv, apache-pig, whitespace

I have comma(,) delimited (`csv`) data set. Where there is a white space after each delimiter which I want to remove in Pig script. Example row looks like:

> ```
> "Sachin", "India", "batsaman", "99", "kolkata", " ", "xyz"
> ```

After removing whitespace after comma it should look like:

> ```
> "Sachin","India","batsaman","99","kolkata"," ","xyz"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Load it into a single field and use REPLACE.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING TextLoader();
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE($0,' ','');
```